# Converting a path to a file on a network drive from macos to windows

Tags: python, windows, macos, path, network-drive

I want to select a file on my Mac, and want the file to be opened on a Windows machine with the path I input on the mac. I have a server the files are located on, maped as follows:

Mac: `/Volumes/myraid/projects/file.txt`

Windows `X:\projects\file.txt`

Is there any way I can convert the path from the mac to any file on the server, to be opened on any windows machine, that is able to access the server? The code to manipulate the path should be executed on the windows machine.

Edit: My main problem is the front part of the path, because windows assigns a different letter for each individual drive (e.g. `X:\`). Especially when I have multiple network drives and I want to be able to select files from all of them.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's the most elegant solution possible. Neither is this solution safe for the same filename with the same filepath existing on multiple drives, but it works for me.

```
import os.path

def findnetworkpath(path_input):    
    path_input = os.path.normpath(path_input) #converts forward slashes to backward slashes
    path_snippet = os.path.join(*path_input.split(os.sep)[2:]) #cuts "Volumes/myraid/" out of the path

    dl = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' 
    drives = ['%s:' % d for d in dl if os.path.exists('%s:' % d)] #checks for existing drives
    for drive in drives:
        if os.path.exists(drive + "\\" + path_snippet):   #checks if the path snippet is the subpath of any connected drives
            return drive + "\\" + path_snippet #function returns the path the windows machine has to the file

print(findnetworkpath("Volumes/myraid/projects/file.txt"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.path.join()`, which joins a list of directories according to the rules of the platform it's run on.

```
>>> # windows
>>> os.path.join('projects', 'file.txt')
projects\file.txt
>>> # mac osx
>>> os.path.join('projects', 'file.txt')
projects/file.txt
```

You can also use `os.name` to get the operating system the program is currently on so you can edit the start of your path accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. I think my explenation of the Problem may have been a bit confusing. Lets say I have multiple network drives on the same server (e.g. myraid, myraid2 and myraid3). Each one of them is detected as an individual network drive. Windows unlike macos and linux assigns different letters for my drives. The problem is not the back end of the path (in this case everything after "myraid"), I can't figure out how to get the Windows path the the selected file from the root and especially how i can make my code independent from the drive letter windows assigns to it.

Comment: Yeah sorry I didn't understand the problem, can't say I could do much better than your solution either